# What is the capitalization standard for class names in the Python Standard Library?

Tags: python, naming-conventions

The norm for Python standard library classes seems to be that class names are lowercase - this appears to hold true for built-ins such as `str` and `int` as well as for most classes that are part of standard library modules that must be imported such as `datetime.date` or `datetime.datetime`.

But, certain standard library classes such as `enum.Enum` and `decimal.Decimal` are capitalized. At first glance, it might seem that classes are capitalized when their name is equal to the module name, but that does not hold true in all cases (such as `datetime.datetime`).

What's the rationale/logic behind the capitalization conventions for class names in the Python Standard Library?

Comment: @VVK, I have updated the answer with more details, please let me know if this helps. If this is good, please remove the negative vote.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The [Key Resources](https://docs.python.org/devguide/#key-resources) section of the Developers Guide lists [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as the style guide.

---

From PEP 8 Naming Conventions, emphasis mine.

> The naming conventions of Python's library **are a bit of a mess**, so
>   we'll never get this completely consistent -- nevertheless, here are
>   the **currently recommended** naming standards. New modules and packages
>   (including third party frameworks) **should be** written to these
>   standards, but where an existing library has a different style,
>   **internal consistency is preferred**.

---

[Also from PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide
>   is important. Consistency within a project is more important.
>   Consistency within one module or function is the most important.
>   ...
>
> Some other good reasons to ignore a particular guideline:
>
> - To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for historic reasons) -- although this is also an opportunity to clean
>     up someone else's mess (in true XP style).
> - Because the **code in question predates the introduction of the guideline** and there is no other reason to be modifying that code.

---

You probably will never know why Standard Library naming conventions conflict with PEP 8 but it is probably a good idea to follow it for new stuff or even in your own projects.

Comment: BeautifulSoup has put work into following current naming standards, while also being backward compatible. Maybe the standard library should too?

Comment: Yep I have seen comments regarding this and the standard library. i'ts nice to be able to point to standard library code for examples - in general.

Answer (score 0):

Pep 8 is considered to be the standard style guide by many Python devs. This recommends to name classes using CamelCase/CapWords.

The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.

Note that there is a separate convention for builtin names: most builtin names are single words (or two words run together), with the CapWords convention used only for exception names and builtin constants.

Check this [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for PEP8 naming conventions and standards.

datetime is a part of standard library,

Python’s standard library is very extensive, offering a wide range of facilities as indicated by the long table of contents listed below. The library contains **built-in modules** (written in C) that provide access to system functionality such as file I/O that would otherwise be inaccessible to Python programmers, as well as modules written in Python that provide standardized solutions for many problems that occur in everyday programming.

In some cases, like sklearn, nltk, django, the package names are all lowercase. This [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) will take you there.

Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

When an extension module written in C or C++ has an accompanying Python module that provides a higher level (e.g. more object oriented) interface, the C/C++ module has a leading underscore (e.g. _socket ).

I hope this covers all the questions.

Comment: Got it, so the CamelCased class names in the standard library are just a relic of the legacy conventions. Thanks. I'm familiar with the standard naming conventions... just wasn't sure if there was some other rule for the standard library that I was missing.

Comment: PEP8 still recommend camel case for class names. Most essential standard library class names have lower case names though.

Comment: Your statements don't hold any water. Where are you getting this information from? PEP8 as you mention states the exact opposite: "[Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)" They just use a different convention for builtins all together (with no real reason why). "Note that there is a separate convention for builtin names: most builtin names are single words (or two words run together), with the CapWords convention used only for exception names and builtin constants."

Comment: Thanks for that Jeff. I read the snake_case thing somewhere. I couldn't find that document anywhere now. Thanks for correction.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Rahul, I removed the accepted answer. This doesn't fully answer my question.  datetime.datetime is part of the standard library but is not a built in, yet it *does not* follow the CamelCase standard. enum.Enum is also part of the standard library but is not a built it, yet it *does* follow the CamelCase standard. What's the reason for this?

Comment: enum is also part of standard library in python 3.4, According to PEP 345 [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/).